# vb.net highlight text in word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, automation

I am using VB.NET in VS 2012 Express to automate Word 2010.
I am trying to find a string and then highlight it in Turquoise.  My code works to find and highlight it, but it does it in the default yellow color.  How can I change that to the desired color?

I apologize if this is a silly question, I am teaching myself VB by writing this.

```
For x As Integer = 0 To (dateConnected.Count() - 1)

    With oRng.Find
        .MatchCase = False
        .ClearFormatting()
        .Text = dateConnected(x)

        With .Replacement
             .ClearFormatting()
             .Text = dateConnected(x)
             .Highlight = Word.WdColor.wdColorTurquoise
        End With
       .Execute(Replace:=Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll)
    End With
Next
```

Comment: As a suggestion, try moving the `Execute` line after the `with`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately there was no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [Highlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195308.aspx) property accept true or false,
the color index is determined by the [DefaultHighlightColorIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa212740%28v=office.11%29.aspx) property, Which member Option property of application instance.

code:

```
 ApplicationInstant.Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = Word.WdColorIndex.wdTurquoise
 .Highlight = True
```

Comment: This was exactly the answer I needed.  Thanks!