# Runnable code snippets in Microsoft Outlook Mails?

Tags: javascript, python, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible to write and execute python, perl, javascript snippets in outlook mails?

The idea is to allow users to write embedded python code in outlook mails, it should take care of

1. highlighting the syntax as user types in the code.
2. should provide an inline button to mail receiver to run the snippet.

Example:

```
    %python
    <python code>
    %endpython

    %perl
    <perl code>
    %endperl
```

Something similar to stackoverflow snippets:

[Feedback requested: Runnable code snippets in questions and answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)
https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1):

No, That would be a huge security hole. No scripts are ever executed in HTML emails by Outlook. More than that, HTML in Outlook is displayed by Word, not IE.

Comment: Can you please ellaborate the security concerns?

Is this even feasible to do with outlook plugins?

Comment: COM addin - sure. You can use the Word Editor API to highlight the text.

Comment: some example for reference?

Comment: Retrieve the Word.Document object from either Explorer.PreviewPane.WordEditor / Inspector.WordEditor or Explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor. Once you have that object, you can use Word Object Model to highlight any text - see, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158886/how-to-highlight-text-in-a-word-document-using-visual-basic